# How to trigger Set method in IConfigurationProvider in .Net Core while using custom configuration provider

Tags: asp.net-core

This is my configuration provider class. I am trying to figure out a way to implement a custom configuration source with a SQL Server database without using Entity Framework (I am using Dapper).

```
public class ReviewProcessDbConfigurationProvider : ConfigurationProvider
{
    private readonly SqlConnection _connection;

    public ReviewProcessDbConfigurationProvider(SqlConnection connection)
    {
        _connection = connection;
    }

    public override void Load()
    {
        try
        {
            var model = _connection.QueryAsync<ProcessConfigurationModel>(ProcessConfigurationQuery.GetProcessConfigurations).Result;
            Data = model.ToDictionary(x => x.ConfigKey, x => x.ConfigValue);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Data.Add(Application.Constants.Constants.Exceptions.ProcessConfigurationLoadException, ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public override void Set(string key, string value)
    {
        try
        {
            var model = _connection.Execute(ProcessConfigurationQuery.UpdateProcessConfiguration, new string[] { key, value});
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

This is how my Program.cs looks like

```
    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
        {
            config.AddDbConfiguration();
        })
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

This load method works as expected. My aim is to trigger the set method using code so the database is updated and also on change is also triggered so that next time I inject `IOptionsMonitor` I get the updated values.

I tried updating the dictionary directly after injecting `IOptionsMonitor` but the set method was not triggered.

Comment: Hi @Rena, I wanted to know if I could trigger the set method using strongly typed options pattern classes such as IOptions/IOptionsMonitor etc, But this works as well. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Set` method will be triggered when you set a configuration value for the specified key.

For example,you could call an `IConfiguration` in your controller and set a data for the configuration with the specific key,then it would dynamiclly call `Set` method:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    public HomeController(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _configuration["AllowedHosts"] = "*";
    }
    //....
}
```

Result:
[image]

If you want this method to be triggered when the application run,you could call this method in `Load()`:

```
public override void Load()
{
      //....
     Set("KeyName", "KeyValue");        
}
```